# Java Count elements of array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to coding, taking a online course at the moment. Now I'm stuck, and I cant find anything to help min move on. The task is to randomly print the amount of number given to the program. Input 5, and the program gives you 5 random numbers. After that sorting them in odd and even. This is all fine.

My problem is that I don't know how to count the numbers in each array (not adding them together) but counting how many odd numbers there is and how any even numbers there is.

Looking for help and guidance.

P.s sorry if there is an answer out there, did my best to find it before asking. d.s

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class RandomNbrs {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many random numbers do you want? (0-999)");
    int numb = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Your random numbers:");

    int array[] = new int[numb];

    for(int i =0; i < numb; i++){

        array [i] = (int) (0 + 1000  * Math.random()); 
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");


    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Even numbers: ");


    for(int j =0; j < numb; j++){

        if(array[j] %2 == 0){


            System.out.print(array[j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }


    }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Odd numbers: ");

    int oddNbr = 0;

    for(int k =0; k < numb; k++){

        if(array[k] %2 == 1){


            System.out.print(array[k]);
            System.out.print(" ");

        }

    }


}



 }
```

Comment: Well you already have a counter for Odd Numbers i.e. `oddNbr`. You just have to increment it by doing `oddNbr++` inside the `if` condition where you are checking the condition. Make similar counter for Even Numbers as well and do the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post to use correct spelling and punctuation. This and other tips may be found on the [Asking help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user2004685, thanks! I have tried that. But i cant seem to get it right. I want one printed number whit the count of the array. Problem me doing it wrong.

Comment: my code didnt work? @forTheLoveOfJava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved the task:

public class testTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int oddCounter=0; 
    int evenCounter=0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many random numbers do you want? (0-999)");
    int numb = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Your random numbers:");

    int array[] = new int[numb];

    for(int i =0; i < numb; i++){

        array [i]  = (int) (0 + 1000  * Math.random()); 

        System.out.print(array[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");


    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();


    for(int j =0; j < numb; j++){

        if(array[j] %2 == 0){
            evenCounter++;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Dessa " + evenCounter + " Even numbers: ");
    for(int j =0; j < numb; j++){


        if(array[j] %2 == 0){


            System.out.print(array[j]);
            System.out.print(" ");

        }

    }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();




    for(int k =0; k < numb; k++){

        if(array[k] %2 == 1){
            oddCounter++;

        }

    }
    System.out.println("Dessa " + oddCounter +  " Odd numbers: ");
    for(int k =0; k < numb; k++){

        if(array[k] %2 == 1){

            System.out.print(array[k]);
            System.out.print(" ");

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts that you've probably misunderstood.

1. You say you need to create two different array for odd and even numbers. However, in the code that you have provided I only see 1 array called 'array'. Note that array[j] and array[k] refer to the same array. j and k are variables.

So, in case you really need two different array for the two numbers, you need to create two more arrays. 
There are several ways, but this would be the simplest (might not necessarily be the best though) going by your code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RandomNbrs
{public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many random numbers do you want? (0-999)");
int numb = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println("Your random numbers:");

int array[] = new int[numb];
int temp,countOdd=0,countEven=0;

for(int i =0; i < numb; i++){
//I am storing the random generated number in a temporary variable
//Then i check if it is odd or even and increase the count by using a counter

    temp= (int) (0 + 1000  * Math.random()); 
    if (temp%2 == 0):
        countEven++;
    else
        countOdd++;
    array[i]=temp

    System.out.print(array[i]);
    System.out.print(" ");


}
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
//Here i am creating two new arrays as you specified. 
//if you just want to print the odd and even numbers AND their couns, you dont necessarily need to make these two arrays.
int arrayOdd[] = new int[countOdd];
int arrayEven[]=new int[countEven];

//Counter for accessing the elements of the two new arrays
int counter1=0,counter2=0;


//Filling the two new arrays with odd and even numbers from the prev array
for(int j =0; j < numb; j++){

    if(array[j] %2 == 0){

        arrayEven[counter1++]=array[j];
    }

    else
        arrayOdd[counter2++]=array[j];


}

   //Print odd
 System.out.println("Odd:");

for(int k =0; k < countOdd; k++){

        System.out.print(arrayOdd[k]);
        System.out.print(" ");

}
System.out.println("Total odd numbers="+countOdd);
//or arrayOdd.length() also gives the count.
//Similar for printing even numbers
}}
```

Additionally you can also use ArrayList where you can dynamically and directly store odd and even generated random numbers in 2 arrays and you do not need the third common array. Let me know if you'd like to know how to this one. :)

Comment: Thanks! @CoderBC, I will use these examples when i re-wright my code. Like you said i misunderstood that they are variables and not to different arrays.